# Cognos Framework Manager 10.2 SQL Query

Tags: sql, cognos

I have this query in to insert in FM:

```
and  (year(pm.CREATE_TIMESTAMP) * 100) + month(pm.create_timestamp) <= (year(current_timestamp - 1 months) * 100) + month(current_timestamp - 1 months)
```

which get stuck with the following error:

```
XQE-V5-0001 V5 syntax error(s) found:
Encountered "months" at line 45, column 104.
Was expecting one of:
"/*+" ...
"=" ...
")" ...
```

maybe someone has encountered similar issue while inserting SQL Query into Query Subject Definition ?

Answer (score 0):

```
year(current_timestamp - 1 months)
```

is not a valid expression. Use function

```
add_months ( date_expression , integer_expression )
```

instead

Comment: add_months is available in oracle and teradata. current_timestamp - 1 months is not valid for any RDBMS. Plus AFAIR cognos functions can be used if query subject is set to Cognos SQL